# Clean up table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I am attempting to load several Excel files into Power BI.  These files are pretty small (<= ~1k rows).  One of these sources must be cleaned up.  In particular, one of its columns has some bad data.  The correct data is stored in another Excel file.  For example:

```
table bad:
ID    col1
1     0
2     0.5
3     2
4     -3

table correct:
ID    colx
2     1
4     5

desired output:
ID    col1
1     0
2     1
3     2
4     5
```

In SQL or other data visualization tools, I would left join the bad table to the clean table and then coalesce the bad values and correct values.  I know that I have some options on how to implement this in Power BI.  I think one option is to implement it in the query editor (i.e., M).  I think another option is to implement it in the data model (i.e., DAX).  Which option is best?  And, what would the implementation look like (e.g., if M, then what does the query look like)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can do this in DAX, I'd suggest doing it in the query editor. The steps would look roughly like this:

1. Merge the `Correct` table into the `Bad` table using a left outer join on the ID `columns`.

[image: Merge Tables]

2. Expand out the `Correct` table to just get the `Colx` column.

[image: Expand Column]

3. Create a custom column to pick the values you want. (Add Column > Custom Column)

   `if [Colx] = null then [Col1] else [Colx]`

[image: Custom Column]

4. You can remove the `Col1` and `Colx` column if you want or just keep them. If you delete `Col1`, you can rename the `Col2` column to be `Col1`.

---

If you don't want the source tables floating around, you can do all of the above in a single query similar to this:

```
let
    BadSource = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUTJQitWJVjICsfRMwWxjINsIzDIBsnSNlWJjAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, Col1 = _t]),
    CorrectSource = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlLSUTJUitWJVjIBskyVYmMB", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, Colx = _t]),
    Bad = Table.TransformColumnTypes(BadSource,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Col1", type number}}),
    Correct = Table.TransformColumnTypes(CorrectSource,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Colx", type number}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Bad,{"ID"},Correct,{"ID"},"Correct",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Correct" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Correct", {"Colx"}, {"Colx"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Correct", "Col2", each if [Colx] = null then [Col1] else [Colx]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Col1", "Colx"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Col2", "Col1"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Comment: For this type of work (i.e., cleaning up data), I generally remove the correct tables after the bad tables have been cleaned up.  How do I drop / truncate tables after the clean-up?

Comment: You can load them all into the same query in the Advanced Editor. That way you don't have any stray tables left over. See my edit.